# ReportingService Databases running in compatibility range, upgrade recommended

Tags: 2013, upgrade, reporting-services, database

We are running a stand alone SharePoint 2013 install.  I have gotten the following message regarding various databases within the install on different occasions and I am always able to resolve them using some variety of:

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

This one seems like it won't go away.  Can you tell me how I can upgrade my Reporting Service Databases?

The error I am getting is as follows:

> The following databases have versions that are older than the current SharePoint software, but are within the backwards compatible range: 
>   ReportingService_44c3289225564f6e8d0e1ac1b7324e55,
>   ReportingService_44c3289225564f6e8d0e1ac1b7324e55_Alerting,
>   ReportingService_44c3289225564f6e8d0e1ac1b7324e55TempDB.